# Invariant eigenspaces

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $E_\lambda$ an eigenspace of a matrix associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.
Suppose that  $g_iE_{\lambda}=E_{\lambda}$ for any element $g_i$ of a finite group $G$.  Is it true that the linear span of any eigenvector orbit in $E_{\lambda}$ is $E_{\lambda}$ itself? i.e.:
$$
span(g_i w,\;\;g_i\in G,w\in E_{\lambda})=E_{\lambda}
$$

for any choice of an eigenvector $w\in E_{\lambda}$?

Cheers!

Comment: What properties do you want from the action of $G$? If it's just always identity how should this work?

Comment: I was thinking to a finite group which is not the "trivial one" composed by one element.

Comment: But the action on the space could still be trivial that is the identity for each element.

Comment: Correct, you mean that w is an eigenvector for all g_i. What if g_i is not abelian is this possible?

Comment: Just define  $g_ix = x$ for all $x,g_i$. I cannot know if you have some implict assumption on your group action that would exclude that.

Comment: This should not be possible if $G$ is not abelian correct? in fact in general $[g_i,g_j]$ is not zero and they do not have common eigenvectors.

Comment: The only properties a group action has to fulfill are that $id \  x = x$ and $g(hx) = (gh)x$. Both are clearly true for the action is specified. Once again if you want to impose something else say so.

Comment: ok so I would like to know under which conditions is true. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: It's not necessarily true even if the  action is faithful. I cannot think of a natural condition that would give this, but maybe there is one. Anyway you might want to update the post via an [edit].

Comment: It's true for all nonzero $w \in E_\lambda$ iff the action of the group on $E_\lambda$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers! If i suppose that the matrix (whose eigenvectors are $g_iw$) has the form:$T=\sum_{i}g_iMg^T_{i}$ and so that $[T,g_i]=0 \forall i$ does this say that $G$ acts irredubibly on $E_{\lambda}$?

Comment: @ Robert :I think is not difficult to prove that  the linear span of the orbit of $w$ is the smallest subspace that contains $w$ that is left invariant by the group action  and therefore (correct?)  the group acts irreducibly on it. Why is then true that this implies that it coincides with $E_{\lambda}$? Thanks!